# Change application theme with C++

Tags: c++, uwp, themes

I'm trying to implement a settings page (with XAML and C++), with three radio buttons: "Light", "Dark" and "Use system theme". How do I do `Application.RequestedTheme`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.application.requestedtheme?view=winrt-19041#remarks) about Application.RequestedTheme, it mentions

> The theme can only be set when the app is started, not while it's
> running. Attempting to set RequestedTheme while the app is running
> throws an exception (NotSupportedException for Microsoft .NET code).
> If you give the user an option to pick a theme that's part of app UI,
> you must save the setting in the app data and apply it when the app is
> restarted.

So you could save the setting of theme in the app data and apply it in the constructorof App when you restart your app. For example:

App.xaml.cpp:

```
App::App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Suspending += ref new SuspendingEventHandler(this, &App::OnSuspending);

    auto value = Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings->Values->Lookup(L"themeSetting");
    if (value != nullptr)
    {
        String^ colorS = safe_cast<String^>(value);
        // Apply theme choice.
        if (colorS == L"Dark") {
            App::Current->RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme::Dark;
        }
        else {
            App::Current->RequestedTheme = ApplicationTheme::Light;
        }
    }
}
```

Setting.xaml.cpp:

```
void AppCX::BlankPage::Light_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings->Values->Insert(L"themeSetting", ApplicationTheme::Light.ToString());
}


void AppCX::BlankPage::Dark_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings->Values->Insert(L"themeSetting", ApplicationTheme::Dark.ToString());
}

void AppCX::BlankPage::UseSystemTheme_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    auto DefaultTheme = ref new Windows::UI::ViewManagement::UISettings();
    auto uiTheme = DefaultTheme->GetColorValue(Windows::UI::ViewManagement::UIColorType::Background).ToString();
    
    if (uiTheme == Windows::UI::Colors::Black.ToString()) {
        Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings->Values->Insert(L"themeSetting", ApplicationTheme::Dark.ToString());
    }
    else if (uiTheme == Windows::UI::Colors::White.ToString())
    {
        Windows::Storage::ApplicationData::Current->LocalSettings->Values->Insert(L"themeSetting", ApplicationTheme::Light.ToString());
    }
}
```